# Python - BS4: Extract Text between between div |

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

Objective:

My objective is to get data/text between div `class="alert-info"` as soon as payload is generated

```
<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped">data</div>
```

Background:

I've posted data successfully in local Server URL and it returned/generated payload in the same URL. Now my next step is to store that particular payload in a variable. URL remain same, before and after generating the payload

Troubleshooting:

Inspect Element before generating the Payload is:

```
<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped"></div>
```

Inspect Element After generating the Payload:

```
<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped">DATA</div>
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#This data will post to the URL
login_data1 = {
    'ABC':'ZYZ'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://localhost/'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    login_data1['App'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'AppKey'})['value']
    d = s.post(url, params=login_data1) # , data=login_data,
    print(r.text.strip()) 
# Till here, payload is generated and I can see it in  <div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped">data</div>

#Tries - Not Succeeded
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    Payload = soup.findAll('span', {"class":"alert-info"}).decode_contents()
    print(Payload)
```

How can we achieve it? using Inner/Outer HTML, CSS Selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sundeep
Thanks a lot for your wonderful support and help. Posting the answer here.
Class "col-lg-1" is used instead of "alert-info"

```
url = 'URL'
r = s.get(url)
resp = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
# print(resp.prettify())
Payload = resp.findAll('div', {"class":"col-lg-12"})[0].text
print(Payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking to extract text from a tag if that's the case,

Assuming `r` is `<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped">DATA</div>`

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped">DATA</div>', 'html.parser')
Payload = soup.findAll('div', {"class":"alert-info"})
print(Payload[0].string)
```

Result:

```
DATA
```

If you need the `findAll` to be in a span make sure you iterate an get the `.string` for every element to get the inner text.
Documentation link : [.string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

Make sure you are adding a sample response to the question if you need additional clarification.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for your answer.
In this case, we are hard coding the data as "DATA", while it is randomly generating.




https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dTtrwj_kx8NcijGnZy8ruB-qfQLqSwdm?usp=sharing

Comment: No, you can simply pass the response which you get and there is no need to hard code and add the HTML tag. I added that to show you an example as I do not have access to the API endpoint.

Comment: sorry my comment was incomplete.
Hi Sandeep, Thanks for your answer.
In this case, we are hard coding the data as "DATA", and as per your code, it will print DATA as well, 
while in my case, it is generating randomly every time.
I tried to explain my issue, in a video attached in below shared URL.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dTtrwj_kx8NcijGnZy8ruB-qfQLqSwdm?usp=sharing

Comment: As far as I understood you are basically sending some values to generate the payload with an `API` and the response will be HTLM content which has the payload in the `Div` tag with the class named `alert-info` and you need to get the text inside the tag, correct?

Comment: Correct. This what i am trying to achieve. (This is actually generating encrypted)
I will use this value and send to Rest API Server

Comment: Then just take whatever response you get from the API and just used the code which I shared and it should work just fine.

Comment: It is printing None.

    soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="alert-info col-lg-12 wrapped"></div>', 'html.parser')
    Payload = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "alert-info"})
    print(Payload[0].string)

If you are available, I can share remote Access. Highly Appreciated

Comment: user158615

I hope this is the one. As this is my first question

Comment: GITHUB ID: rbm179

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am learning a lot from you.
I signed in gitter.Im.

Comment: Message sent. Really appreciate your help.